# difference between rvm_env_string and rvm_ruby_string?

Tags: ruby, bash, unix, rvm, environment-variables

Just curious, as one of the lessons [here](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/) has me searching for the definitions of all variables in my work environment.

Both return "ruby-2.0.0-p247" and I'm *guessing* that rvm_ruby_string is the version of ruby used in rvm, while rvm_env_string is the....environment? Confused.

Comment: where is in the lessons link to `rvm`?

Comment: rvm specifically isn't in the lessons, but figuring out what my environment variables do is part of this one http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex22.html

Comment: *rvm* just set properly the evn variables up, see: `env|grep rvm`, downcase vars are used by rvm, upcase are used externally by others.

Comment: in my case: `env|grep rvm.*string
rvm_ruby_string=ruby-2.1.0` only. And there is no `rvm_env_string` var existed